# How do I implement a spinning ProgressBar on a AsyncTask while the data is loading?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

Let's say I have this code:

XML

```
 <FrameLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/photo_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Program

```
  private class FetchItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<GalleryItem>> {
    private String mQuery;


    public FetchItemsTask(String query) {
        mQuery = query;
    }
    @Override
    protected List<GalleryItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (mQuery == null) {
            return new FlickrFetchr().fetchRecentPhotos();
        } else {
            return new FlickrFetchr().searchPhotos(mQuery);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<GalleryItem> galleryItems) {
        mItems = galleryItems;
        setupAdapter();

    }
}
```

How do I implement a spinning ProgressBar and hide the RecyclerView while the AsycnTask does its work in the background? Sorry if this seems like a simple question, but the only answers that I've found use ProgressDialog, which is deprecated as of API 26. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `ProgressBar` is deprecated because its blocking UI. And google thinks you should do it this way, but instead you should show loadingSpinner in your view. But if you dont care you can use ProgressDialog just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Override the Pre-execute Method and show the progress dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the spinner in `onPreExecute()` and hide it in `onPostExecute()`.

```
class Your_Class extends AsyncTask<...>
{
    ProgressBar pb;
    Your_Class(){
    // initialize pb
    }
    Protected void onPreExecute(){
        // show progressbar
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image){
        // hide progressbar
    }
}
```